# Default validation for datetime-local is disable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, validation, datetime

I create a website using ASP.NET MVC and meet a problem with datetime-local type as following:

● In the view page I put 2 lines for datetime as following:

```
@Html.TextBox(property.Name, "2017/08/24T09:31:00", new {@type="datetime-local", @step="1", @class="form-control"});
@Html.ValidationMessage(property.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

When user input into date field an invalid value, for example 2017/**02**/**31** 01:01:01, then click button to post, Html5 will display a validate message:
[Html5 default validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc5Ge.png)

● When I add the following script to enable client validation:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Then when I input into date field an invalid value, for example 2017/02/31 01:01:01, and click button to post to server. Default Html5 validation message isn't appear. And the value of date send to server is null.
I want to keep both client validation of asp.net and Html5 validation for datetime-local but because of asp.net knowledge limitation, I have no idea for this case.
Someone can suggest some idea for me.

On the other hand, I don't know where is path of ~/bundles/jqueryval. Can anybody explain for me?
PS: I'm sorry for my English skill.

Comment: Its confusing, *I want to keep both client validation of asp.net and Html5 validation*. HTML5 validation is also client side validation, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I add @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
} to validate client-side for integer or other type, the validation message(in image link above) for date time is no longer displayed when I input invalid date (2017/02/31)

Comment: Have you found any errors in console? It is possible to override `ValidationMessage` by custom client-side validation schema (including jquery.validate), check the scripts there.

Comment: To Tetsuya Yamamoto: I debug and see that the value when it send to jquery is empty. You can see in the link [https://ibb.co/hFpNe5]. When I don't use jquery-validate, html5 somehow can validate such invalid value.